# Does it make sense to use Firestore Realtime as a way to interact with functions?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a good old fashioned piece of code that takes some inputs, runs some code and produces outputs for a variety of tasks. This code runs in a function, and it should be triggered by a UI action. It is relevant to store a history of these runs per user, to list them in a specific view of the UI, and, on returning users, put them back where they left.

Since the Firestore documentation and [videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3aoxOtMM2rc&t=85s) strongly encourage us to default to it for data exchange with the backend, I of course decided to entertain the idea before just moving on to simply implementing a callable.

First, it made sense to me to model the data as follows:

```
/users
  id

  /taskRuns
    id
    inputs
    outputs

    /history
      id
      date
      ...outputs
```

and make the data flow as follows:

1. The UI writes to the `inputs` field and it listens to the document.
2. The unction is triggered. It runs happily and it writes to `outputs`.

   - A second function listening to `/assets` puts copies over the inputs and outputs onto its corresponding `/history` subcollection.
3. The UI reacts to the change.

At this point, a couple of red flags are raised on my mind:

- Since the UI has to both read and write `/assets`, a malicious user could technically trigger infinite loops here. I'm aware that the same thing is possible with a callable, but it somehow seems even easier in this scenario.
- I lose the ability to do timeout and error handling the way one would with a simple API call.

However, I also understand that:

- My function needs to write to the database anyway to store the outputs even if it was returning it à la API.
- Logic for who's responsible for what has somewhat been broken down into pieces.

So - Am I looking at it wrong? Is there a world in which this approach would make sense over the callable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach you're describing uses the database as a queue/cache/proxy for your backend functionality. I regularly use it myself with either Realtime Database or Firestore to expose backend functionality, because it:

- Works more gracefully when there's intermittent loss of internet connection. Where a direct call to Cloud Functions would have to implement its own retries, the database SDKs already handle this scenario.
- Uses the database as a proxy/cache for the result, so that repeated loads of the data don't cause additional calls to my Cloud Functions.
- By setting a maximum number of instances on my Cloud Function, I can prevent overloading any legacy infrastructure my code calls, and the database becomes my queue of pending requests.

The pattern is also used in this video from Cloud Next 2019: [Serverless in real life: a case study in the travel industry](https://youtu.be/-qR4KC3JwNk) and this talk from Google I/O: [Architecting for Data Contention in a Realtime World with Firebase](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eWj6dxfN63g).

That said, many of my team mates only ever use callable functions, so it's definitely a matter of preference and the requirements of your use-case.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. However, I believe points 2 and 3 are also easily achievable with the callable + a listener on the database, right? Would, in your opinion, exposing less permissions (r vs rw) on the client and therefore minimizing the possible event loops, ever outweigh the benefits you mention? If so, where's this boundary?

Comment: You can [limit permissions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started) on the database-backed approach equally as you can when calling cloud functions directly.